# Android Studio and Kotlin REPL > Trouble importing classes in REPL

Tags: android, kotlin

I am writing Kotlin classes that I wish to test in the Kotlin REPL on Android. When I start up the REPL and try to import my class I'm getting an "Unresolved Reference" error. I'm struggling to figure out what path needs to be put in front of the class name.

My path is "C:\Users\Odidn\AndroidStudioProjects\GDC" (GDC being the project name), and The package on all of these files in my app is "com.odidn.gdc" however when I try import com.odidn.gdc.Dungeon, import gdc.Dungeon, (or any length/combination of the words in the package/my path) I still get an Unresolved Reference error. Is there something simple I'm missing?